# App crashes when I try to get the _id in my SQLite Table?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Hi guys so here is my problem, I need to be able to access the unique ID of a row that is created because I created a second table that will "Connected" through the IDs. However here is my issue, whenever I try calling this method, my app crashes.. I was hoping the community could help me out here. Many Thanks.

```
public void addExerciseToDatabase(Exercises exercises){

    SQLiteDatabase db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    ContentValues nuValues = new ContentValues();

    values.put(myDBHelper.COLUMN_BODYPARTNAME, exercises.get_bodyPart());
    values.put(myDBHelper.COLUMN_EXERCISENAME, exercises.get_exerciseName());

    long ID = db.insert(myDBHelper.TABLE_EXERCISES, null, values);

    //FOR THE NEW TABLE VALUES
    nuValues.put(myDBHelper.COLUMN_EXERCISENAME_ID, ID);
    nuValues.put(myDBHelper.COLUMN_NUMSETS, exercises.get_numSets());
    nuValues.put(myDBHelper.COLUMN_NUMWEIGHT, exercises.get_numWeight());
    nuValues.put(myDBHelper.COLUMN_NUMREPS, exercises.get_numReps());

    db.insert(myDBHelper.TABLE_EXERCISES_VALUE, null, nuValues);
    db.close();
}

/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
THIS method returns the EXERCISE ID, that corresponds to the exercise
passed and Bodypart passed
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
public int getExerciseID(String exercise, String bodyPart) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String query = "SELECT " + myDBHelper.COLUMN_ID + " FROM " + myDBHelper.TABLE_EXERCISES + " WHERE " +
            myDBHelper.COLUMN_BODYPARTNAME + " = " + bodyPart + " AND " +
            myDBHelper.COLUMN_EXERCISENAME + " = " + exercise ;

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    int exerciseID = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0));
    /*int exerciseID = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(myDBHelper.COLUMN_ID));*/
    c.close();
    db.close();

    return exerciseID;
}
```

**HERES MY TABLE:**

```
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "exercises.db";

    public static final String TABLE_EXERCISES = "exercises";
    public static final String TABLE_EXERCISES_VALUE = "exercises_value";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_BODYPARTNAME = "bodypartname";
    public static final String COLUMN_EXERCISENAME = "exercisename";

    public static final String COLUMN_EXERCISENAME_ID = "exerciseid";
    public static final String COLUMN_NUMSETS = "numsets";
    public static final String COLUMN_NUMWEIGHT = "numweight";
    public static final String COLUMN_NUMREPS = "numreps";


    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EXERCISES + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_BODYPARTNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                COLUMN_EXERCISENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL" +
                ");";

        db.execSQL(query);

        query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EXERCISES_VALUE + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_EXERCISENAME_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                COLUMN_NUMSETS + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                COLUMN_NUMWEIGHT + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                COLUMN_NUMREPS + " INTEGER NOT NULL" +
                ");";

        db.execSQL(query);
    }
```

Comment: it would help a lot if you posted the stack trace but my guess is the fact that there are no spaces in `"SELECT" + myDBHelper.COLUMN_ID + "FROM " `

Comment: noted and changed, however it is still crashing when i try to access this method. Also sorry Im new to this so how would i go about getting a stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your query as your query not contains spaces in SELECT and FROM

```
String query = "SELECT " + myDBHelper.COLUMN_ID + " FROM " + myDBHelper.TABLE_EXERCISES + " WHERE " +
            myDBHelper.COLUMN_BODYPARTNAME + " = " + bodyPart + " AND " +
            myDBHelper.COLUMN_EXERCISENAME + " = " + exercise ;
```

Also can you post your logcat error.

```
    public int getExerciseID(String exercise, String bodyPart) {
        int exerciseID = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        String query = "SELECT " + myDBHelper.COLUMN_ID + " FROM " + myDBHelper.TABLE_EXERCISES + " WHERE " +
                myDBHelper.COLUMN_BODYPARTNAME + " = " + bodyPart + " AND " +
                myDBHelper.COLUMN_EXERCISENAME + " = " + exercise ;

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if(c.getCount()>0){
          c.moveToFirst();
          exerciseID = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0));
          /*exerciseID = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(myDBHelper.COLUMN_ID));*/
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();

        return exerciseID;
    }
```

Comment: noted and changed, how would i go about getting a log cat error. Is it something like this? Log.e("DB", "error")

Comment: when your application crashed, error gets printed on the logcat in eclipse.

Comment: Sorry but stackoverflow dosent seem to like the what im trying to post, something about my code not being formatted properly, but as i was looking through it I found this which looked interesting      Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: ok got it.
Your cursor is empty. so thats why your application crashes

Comment: How would i go about fixing that, also what does it mean by my cursor is empty? Does that mean that whatever im trying to retreive is empty? Since the data im trying to get is the unique _id thats being auto incremented

Comment: I tried the updated code and it resolves the it from crashing however, c.getCount() > 0 is always false... Do you have any idea why that could be? I use SQLite manager so i can visually see that I indeed have the IDs populated

Comment: it means that your database is having no records for bodypart and exercise you are searching.

Comment: I see, well, i try to see what I can do from here on, but your code did solve the original problem of it crashing so thank you very much!!